# Search 0KB files in a folder C#

Tags: c#

hi
How can I find the files in  a folder which are of size 0 KB using c#.

Regards,
Creator

Comment: Define `0kb` please. Is it the same as `0 bytes`? Or just `< 1024 bytes`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are objects in System.IO (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx) to help you

Answer (score 2):

```
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\");
    FileInfo[] fiArr = di.GetFiles();
    foreach (FileInfo fri in fiArr)
        if (fri.Length < minimalSizeRequirement) 
          this.IamDoneFor();
```

---

Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you really want *0 byte* files, perhaps this will do:

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\your\path");
FileInfo[] zeroSizeFiles = di.GetFiles("*.*")
    .Where(fi => fi.Length == 0)
    .ToArray();
```